# How do I "read" from an existing image object instead of a file path with PerlMagick?

Tags: perl, imagemagick, montage, perlmagick

The following code generates a 300x100 image using a 100x100 tile as a source image:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $image->Read("filepath/100x100.png");
}

$result = $image->Montage(geometry=>'100x100',tile=>'3x1');
```

How do I reach the same result **while only reading once from disk?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not obvious from the docs, but you can add [clones](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php#miscellaneous) to the image sequence like this:

```
$image->Read("filepath/100x100.png");
$image->[1] = $image->[0]->Clone();
$image->[2] = $image->[0]->Clone();

$result = $image->Montage(geometry=>'100x100',tile=>'3x1');
```

Comment: Is there anything closer to this: `$image->Append($image->[0]->Clone());` So that I don't have to keep track of how many images have already been stored in the object?

Comment: The `Image::Magick` object is just a blessed array, so you can use normal array operators, e.g. `push @$image, $image->[0]->Clone();`. You can get the last index with `$#$image`.